# Flutter, admob dispose not working sometimes

Tags: flutter, admob, firebase-admob

I`m using "firebase_admob" package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob

and my code is below

```
static void hideBannerAd() {
 if (_bannerAd != null) {
        _bannerAd.dispose();
       _bannerAd = null;
     }
}
```

All of my ads functions are defined as static and this works perfectly.

Currently I am turning off ads on my app's specific page.

However, since releasing my app, certain customers have found that hideBannerAd is not working properly.

On a particular page, they say that there are times when the ad is turned off well and sometimes it is not,  once it is not turned off, it will never turn off(Even if they go in and out of that particular app's screen page) .

On my device this works perfectly without any of error.

If you turn off and turn on the AdMob banner frequently, is there a case where the network is tangled and it does not work properly?

Any advices would be appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem on a project a while ago, this is a package bug. Here are a few similar unresolved GitHub issues : [#96](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/96), [#669](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/669), [#3056](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3056), [#3900](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3900). The package have been poorly maintained, but this might change due to the recent FluterFire reorganization.